# How is Flink integration testing working without the documented flink-test-utils dependency or MiniClusterWithClientResource?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm using Flink 1.15.1 and JUnit5. I would like to know how the following integration test, adapted from the [documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/datastream/testing/#testing-flink-jobs), works without the inclusion of the `flink-test-utils` dependency and the `MiniClusterWithClientResource` static instance.

```
package com.mypackage;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.SinkFunction;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class ExampleIntegrationTest {

  @Test
  public void testIncrementPipeline() throws Exception {
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    // configure your test environment
    env.setParallelism(2);

    // values are collected in a static variable
    CollectSink.values.clear();

    // create a stream of custom elements and apply transformations
    env.fromElements(1L, 21L, 22L).map(n -> n + 1).addSink(new CollectSink());

    // execute
    env.execute();

    // verify your results
    assertTrue(CollectSink.values.containsAll(List.of(2L, 22L, 23L)));
  }

  // create a testing sink
  private static class CollectSink implements SinkFunction<Long> {

    // must be static
    public static final List<Long> values = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

    @Override
    public void invoke(Long value, SinkFunction.Context context) throws Exception {
      values.add(value);
    }
  }
}
```

Am I missing something crucial by not including the `flink-test-utils` dependency and the `MiniClusterWithClientResource` static instance that make my integration tests incorrect? The documentation is specific that those are required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the `@ClassRule` shown in the documentation, you'll be spinning up a new Flink mini-cluster for every test (configured with the defaults) rather than reusing the same cluster (with its specific configuration) for all of the tests in that test class.

For a more up-to-date JUnit5 setup, you could look at how the tests are organized in the Immerok Apache Flink cookbook, i.e., [FlinkMiniClusterExtension](https://github.com/immerok/recipes/blob/main/kafka-json-to-pojo/src/test/java/com/immerok/cookbook/extensions/FlinkMiniClusterExtension.java) which looks like this:

```java
package com.immerok.cookbook.extensions;

import org.apache.flink.runtime.testutils.MiniClusterResourceConfiguration;
import org.apache.flink.test.util.MiniClusterWithClientResource;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.AfterAllCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeAllCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

/**
 * A wrapper around a {@link MiniClusterWithClientResource} that allows it to be used as a JUnit5
 * Extension.
 */
public class FlinkMiniClusterExtension implements BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FlinkMiniClusterExtension.class);

    private static final int PARALLELISM = 2;
    private static MiniClusterWithClientResource flinkCluster;

    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        flinkCluster =
                new MiniClusterWithClientResource(
                        new MiniClusterResourceConfiguration.Builder()
                                .setNumberSlotsPerTaskManager(PARALLELISM)
                                .setNumberTaskManagers(1)
                                .build());

        flinkCluster.before();

        LOG.info("Web UI is available at {}", flinkCluster.getRestAddres());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterAll(ExtensionContext context) {
        flinkCluster.after();
    }
}
```

and it gets used like this:

```java
@ExtendWith(FlinkMiniClusterExtension.class)
class MyTests ...
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I work for Immerok.

Answer (score 2):

`flink-test-utils` library comes with [`MiniClusterExtension`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-test-utils-parent/flink-test-utils/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/test/junit5/MiniClusterExtension.java) for JUnit 5.

```java
// Creates a mini cluster with 1 task manager and 1 slot per task manager
@ExtendWith(MiniClusterExtension.class)
public class MyTest {
// ...
}
```

OR

```java
public class MyTest {

    @RegisterExtension
    public static final MiniClusterExtension MINI_CLUSTER_RESOURCE = new MiniClusterExtension(
            new MiniClusterResourceConfiguration.Builder()
                    .setNumberSlotsPerTaskManager(2)
                    .setNumberTaskManagers(1)
                    .build());

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        ExecutionEnvironment execEnv = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    }

    @Test
    public void myTest2(@InjectMiniCluster MiniCluster miniCluster) {
        // Use miniCluster
    }

    @Test
    public void myTest3(@InjectClusterClient ClusterClient<?> clusterClient) {
        // clusterClient here is an instance of MiniClusterClient
    }

    @Test
    public void myTest4(@InjectClusterClient RestClusterClient<?> restClusterClient) {
        // Using RestClusterClient as parameter type will force the creation 
        //  of a RestClusterClient, rather than MiniClusterClient
    }

}
```

**P.S.:** `MiniClusterExtension.class` is still marked as `@Experimental` as of v1.16 and therefore subject to changes.

Comment: is it necessary to do `@RegisterExtension` or is `@ExtendWith(MiniClusterExtension.class)` sufficient?

Comment: @r_g_s_ it is either one of them. I extended the answer to add some examples. You can see the source code and class documentation.